# how many options do we have for data compression in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

In TDengine database, there is a data compression configuration in /etc/taos/taos.cfg

```
# enable/disable compression
# comp                  2
```

the default option is 2, so how many options do we have for comp, what is the difference for each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDengine provides three compression options: no compression, one-stage compression and two-stage compression, corresponding to comp values of 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

One-stage compression is carried out according to the type of data. Compression algorithms include delta-delta coding, simple 8B method, zig-zag coding, LZ4 and other algorithms.

Two-stage compression is based on one-stage compression and compressed by general compression algorithm, which has higher compression ratio.